# Initializing a Variable

Tags: c, initialization

Is it **possible** to do something like this in C?

```
typedef XXX bar;
void foo(bar i) {
    ...
}
main() {
    bar a;
    foo(a); // note!!, this is not foo(&a)
    // a is now initialized
}
```

Note that `foo` is a `void` function, otherwise by returning a new bar the problem could be easily solved. Furthermore, I have even if bar was a pointer, or a pointer to a pointer, e.g., `typedef int ** bar`, I don't see how `foo` could initialize `a`

My question was raised since I believe in [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) they do something similar. So in GMP you can have:

```
mpz_t a; 
mpz_init2(a); 
// a is now initialized
```

Comment: `bar i` should be reference (in c++), in c you can simulate them by using pointers

Comment: @Lashane I'm not sure I understand. I'm talking about `C`, so I can only play with pointers.

Comment: a is not initialized before `foo`, so `foo` cannot do `*a = 1` inside it. This would leat to a seg fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://gnu.huihoo.org/gmp-3.1.1/html_chapter/gmp_4.html:

> mpz_t is actually implemented as a one-element array of a certain
>   structure type. This is why using it to declare a variable gives an
>   object with the fields GMP needs, but then using it as a parameter
>   passes a pointer to the object.

Answer (score 2):

Reference semantics can be implemented in C by using pointer parameters in functions and the address-of operator in argument lists:

```
void init(int * dst, int value) { *dst = value; }
//       ^^^^^^
//       function takes parameter by address, passed as a pointer

int main()
{
    int a;
    init(&a, 10);
    //   ^^
    //   caller passes address-of object
}
```

If you want a syntax that lexically omits the address-of operator, you can stick that part into a macro:

```
#define INIT_BY_REF(x, val) init_ref(&(x), val)
```

Now use: `init_ref(a, 10)`

Comment: As you see I'm asking on whether it can be done using `init(a)` (similar to GMP) and not `init(&a)`.

Comment: @foorbar: No, not if `init` is a function. All C arguments are passed by value. You can define a preprocessor macro to apply the address-of operation for you, though. Added.

Comment: You are saying it cannot be done with `init(a)`? I have the feeling that using a preprocessor macro would also mess up the `bar a` before the `foo(a)` call.

Comment: @foorbar: Of course; using a macro for this is a phenomenally terrible idea. But if you must have this specific lexical form, then there's no way around.

Comment: @KerrekSB it can be done, as evinced by the GMP example, i.e. `typedef int bar[1];`   (Whether that is a good idea or not is another matter)

Comment: *"Whether that is a good idea or not is another matter"* This question is a good example of why it's not a good idea.

Comment: @M.M: That's true. If your variable is an array, then you get the address for free. But note that you can then not use the variable like a scalar, so you lose some generality.

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible if the variable being initialized is a pointer or (`typedef`'d) array. I don't have experience with GMP, but that initialization function indicates to me that `mpz_t` is a typedef of a pointer or an array.

If the argument passed is a primitive or struct value, the function will use its own copy of the data and leave the variables passed to it untouched.